# HTML Radio buttons styled as Toggle Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, controls

Instead of having the typical disks with labels to the right, I want the options to be presented as clickable buttons.  The selected option should appear to be pushed or pressed in.

I want to do this in HTML, but an example of this are the top left buttons in the program Audacity where you select the cursor/tool mode.

What's the best way to do this?

[image]
<sub>(source: [freemusicsoftware.info](http://freemusicsoftware.info/screenshots/audacity-linux-small.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of JavaScript plugins for doing this:

- [Prototype demo](http://codetalks.org/source/widgets/checkbox/checkbox1.html)

Just replace the images they're using with your images and you should be good to go.

Comment: The 'Checkize & Radize Demo (jQuery)' link seems dead.

Comment: Thanks, I can't find another link so I've removed it.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the best way is to create a real radio button, and then control the rendering of an element based upon the status on the radio button with javascript. If the radio button is selected, render background-a, else background-b (or use a sprite). Control the status of the radio button via the click event of your custom element.

Answer (score 1):

Using [this jQuery UI plugin](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/checkbox-radiobutton/), you can customize radio buttons and/or checkboxes to look however you want.